# How to map SQL queries to in-memory model objects?

Tags: model-view-controller

Let's say we are structuring an application with MVC (also, Stores/Services). SQL is used as the persistence mechanism. And memory efficiency is a major concern.

Obviously, we should take advantage of SQL queries and only ask for fields of our Model in theory object when they are needed.

For example, an mobile app may need to display a list of title for articles, while the body of the article doesn't get displayed until user taps on a specific title. In this case, we ask SQL for just the titles first.

The question is, what should the model object look like?

The solutions I can think of are:

1. Enhance the model with some states that indicate which fields are populated. This could also be archived by using nil/NULL/None values on unpopulated fields of the model object.
2. Split the theoretical model to multiple classes. Following the previous example, we could have an `Article` class and an `ArticleDetail` class, with a one-to-one relation.
3. Forget the Store object, let each model object lazy evaluate it's costly fields. The model would have to know about its persistence mechanism.

This should be a common problem. How do the ORM in your favorite frameworks/libraries resolve it? Any best practices?

Comment: "And memory efficiency is a major concern" - server or client memotry?

Comment: @jim I had client in mind when this question came up, but you are welcome to provide solutions for either.

Comment: First of all, model is not a class. What you are talking about is either [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject), or (in worst case) some form of [active records](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html). The solution would be to have two separate methods in the [mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) for fetching data from storage: one method for retrieving all the data and another for oly fetching minor details. The alternative would be to separate `Artice` and `Content` domain objects.